# javascript code of an image rotator

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

I am trying to make an 8 image button rotator via javascript, I have buttons "<" ">" "<<" ">>" and a check box image rotator. I can send my code so far and screenshot, can someone help? here is my code.

```
<div id="images">
  <img src="images/sample1.jpg" id="image"/>
</div>
<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button id="firstImageButton" title="Click to view the first image." onClick="previousImage("image")">&laquo;</button>
  <button id="previousImageButton" title="Click to view the previous image." >&lt;</button>
  <button id="nextImageButton" title="Click to view the next image." >&gt;</button>
  <button id="lastImageButton" title="Click to view the last image." onClick="images/sample8.jpg">&raquo;</button>
  <br/><input type="checkbox" id="autoRotate" /><label for="autoRotate">Click to auto-rotate</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

script

```
<script>
  var images = [ "images/sample1.jpg", "images/sample2.jpg", "images/sample3.jpg", "images/sample4.jpg", "images/sample5.jpg", "images/sample6.jpg", "images/sample7.jpg", "images/sample8.jpg" ]
  var currentImageIndex = 0;
  var currentImage = 0;

  function nextImageButton() {
    currentImage += 1;
    displayImage(currentImage);
  }

  function previousImageButton() {
    currentImage -= 1;
    displayPage(currentImage);
  }

  function displayImage (imageIndex) {
    document.getElementById("images").innerHTML = images[imageIndex];   
    document.getElementById("nextImageButton").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("previousImageButton").style.visibility = "visible";

    if(imageIndex == images.length - 1) {
      document.getElementById("nextImageButton").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    if(imageIndex == 0) {
      document.getElementById("previousImageButton").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. change all tabs before posting.
2. create a jsfiddle.net with the code.
3. what's with the `</div></div></div>` ?
4. what is onClick="images/sample8.jpg" supposed to do?
5. you have the same quotes in the onclick - if you wrap quotes you need to do `="...('xxx');"`
6. `document.getElementById("images").innerHTML = images[imageIndex];`
   should be `document.getElementById("image").src = images[imageIndex];`

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/yG7yY/)

```
var images = [ "http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-640-480-1.jpg", 
               "http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-640-480-2.jpg", 
               "http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-640-480-3.jpg", 
               "http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-640-480-4.jpg", 
               "http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-640-480-5.jpg", 
               "http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-640-480-6.jpg", 
               "http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-640-480-7.jpg" ]
var tId,currentImage = 0;

function changeImage(dir) {
  if (dir === 0) currentImage = 0; // first image
  else if (dir===images.length-1) currentImage=images.length-1; // last image
  else currentImage+=dir*1; // next or previous
  if (currentImage<0 || currentImage>=images.length)  currentImage=0; // will wrap
  displayImage(currentImage);
}


function displayImage (imageIndex) {
  window.console && console.log(imageIndex); // remove when happy
  // document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=(imageIndex+1)+"/"+images.length;  
  document.getElementById("image").src = images[imageIndex];   
  document.getElementById("nextImageButton").style.visibility=(imageIndex<images.length-1)?"visible":"hidden";
  document.getElementById("previousImageButton").style.visibility=(imageIndex>0)?"visible":"hidden";
}
function rotate() {
    changeImage(+1);
}
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("autoRotate").onclick=function() {
    if (this.checked) tId=setInterval(rotate,3000)
    else clearInterval(tId);
  }
  document.getElementById("firstImageButton").onclick=function() { changeImage(0) }
  document.getElementById("lastImageButton").onclick=function() { changeImage(images.length-1) }
  document.getElementById("nextImageButton").onclick=function() { changeImage(1) }
  document.getElementById("previousImageButton").onclick=function() { changeImage(-1) }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was still doing trial and error of the code. It is completely messed up. Is the loop you provided for the check box? and can you help me with the buttons and the rest of the code? I appreciate your help.

Comment: can you help? I need the onCLick fixed, and the js code verified and/or fixed.

Comment: Done. That will be 20 minutes of custom coding. 20EUR ex VAT ;)

Comment: you are amazing and an awesome programmer. 2 small questions, What does the === stand for and the "dir" stand for? Again, highest vote possible, your great.

Comment: === is strictly equal to (because false, "" and null are also == to 0) and dir is direction +1/-1 but I abuse it a little and allow 0 and images.length-1 too to go to first or last

Comment: again you are a master at what you do. I hope to chat with you again to help me with Javascript if ever available. Cheers, Sir!